# 'NoMethodError: undefined method' in Ruby on Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, nomethoderror, whenever

I am creating a system that recurring payments each month so I am creating a new payment requirement using the **whenever gem**

The problem seems to be in my Payment model method, which is here.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  def monthly_payment
    clients = Client.all
    clients.each do |client|
      Payment.create(month: Date.now, client_id: client.id)
    end
  end
end
```

In the cron.log I was getting a NoMethodError so I tried the method in the rails console and the same error appears:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `monthly_payment' for Payment (call 'Payment.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

Is there something wrong with the Model?

Here is the schema of Payment:

```
create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.date     "date"
 t.string   "type"
 t.date     "month"
 t.boolean  "paid"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer  "client_id"
end
```

Comment: What's the command being run in cron that calls the code in `Payment` model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a class method, not an instance method:

```
def self.monthly_payment # notice the self.
  clients = Client.all
  clients.each do |client|
    Payment.create(month: Date.now, client_id: client.id)
  end
end
```

So you will be able to call

```
Payment.monthly_payment # class method
# method that can be called only on the Payment class
```

And not

```
Payment.where(some_condition).first.monthly_payment # instance method
# method that can be called only on an instance of the Payment class
```

---

An interesting link about it: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: Silly mistake of mine. Anyway thanks a lot! I had not realised that.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it as a class method, I.e.

```
def Payment.monthly_payment
  # etc.
end
```

Sorry for bad formatting, I'm on mobile.

Comment: (I got your back, I edited your post to format the code)

Comment: Seems like while I was writing this on phone, someone had faster fingers  :)